# iframe height issue within an accordian

Tags: wordpress, iframe, height, sizing

I'm having an issue with an external iframe contained within an accordian on a WordPress website.

Here it is: https://nomoreply.co.uk/6mm-preprimed-tile-backing-boards/

Under the "Quantity Calculator" accordian.

On mobile view the iframe calculator contains alot of empty space at the bottom - I would like to remove this:

[iframe sizing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWqgw.png)

I have tried various height settings both inline and within the iframe tag. Also an external javascript I found on stackoverflow. Nothing has worked.

Comment: Welcome! Please read why [offsite links are not good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a library called iframe-resizer, that you might want to look at. It uses multiple techniques to force an iframe to size to its content. It is a way harder problem than it should be.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, since there isn't a link to your library. FWIW - I have used your library on several sites and it's a fantastic tool.

Comment: No probs, Would be great if you could upvote the answer as well.